# How do I have an "get only if this exists" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My query...

```
   SELECT MIN(p.`land_price`) AS `min_price`,
          MAX(p.`land_price`) AS `max_price`,
          p.`estate`,
          m.`file`

     FROM `properties` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `estates` AS `e`
       ON p.`estate` = e.`title`

LEFT JOIN `media` AS `m`
       ON  m.`category` = e.`id` 

    WHERE p.`estate` IN ("EstateA", "EstateB")
      AND p.`land_price` != 0
 GROUP BY p.`estate
```

What I want to do, is get an item from `media` table (aliased as `m`) where `name = "Profile"`, except to only select if it exists, otherwise just have blank column for others in result set. At the moment, if I add that constraint, it only gives me matches where that `name` exists.

At the moment, it is just selecting the first item in `media` that matches the constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "WHERE" part limits the results from the main table `properties`. In this case you should add another constraint to the "ON" part of the second LEFT JOIN.

Example:

```
SELECT MIN(p.`land_price`) AS `min_price`,
          MAX(p.`land_price`) AS `max_price`,
          p.`estate`,
          m.`file`

     FROM `properties` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `estates` AS `e`
       ON p.`estate` = e.`title`

LEFT JOIN `media` AS `m`
       ON  m.`category` = e.`id` 
       AND m.`name` = 'Profile'

    WHERE p.`estate` IN ("EstateA", "EstateB")
      AND p.`land_price` != 0
 GROUP BY p.`estate
```